# Submitting POST data to a different site and then extracting the output with PHP

Tags: php, html, screen-scraping

I'd like to use the snoopy class, but I don't have the proper server permissions with my shared hosting to install it. Any easy to use alternatives?

I need to submit this POST data:

```
hash = $_POST['hash']
Submit = Submit
```

to this site:

http://milw0rm.com/cracker/info.php

And extract the output in the -::PASS column from

http://milw0rm.com/cracker/search.php

which is where it redirects you when you submit from info.php

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found an even better solution. Using the publicly available snoopy class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use curl_ to make a post, (or zend_http_client) then grab the response body and parse.

Comment: Found an even better solution. Using the publicly available snoopy class.